# Rust "attempt to multiply with overflow" when using .pow() function

Tags: rust

I am trying to solve
[Magnet particules in boxes](https://www.codewars.com/kata/56c04261c3fcf33f2d000534/rust)

Here is my code:

```rust
fn doubles(maxk: i32, maxn: i32) -> f64 {
    let mut result: f64 = 0.0;
    let mut k = 1;
    let mut n = 1;

    while k <= maxk {
        while n <= maxn {
            result += 1.0 / (k as i64 * (((n + 1) as i32).pow((2 * k) as u32)) as i64) as f64;
            n += 1;
        }
        n = 1;
        k += 1;
    }

    result
}
```

Tests like gives me an error "attempt to multiply with overflow"

```rust
dotest(10, 1000, 0.6921486500921933);
dotest(10, 10000, 0.6930471674194457);
```

Trouble with `pow()` function.
How could I modify my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `f64`, because it has bigger range than integer.

```
   fn doubles(maxk: i32, maxn: i32) -> f64 {
       let mut result: f64 = 0.0;
       let mut k = 1;
       let mut n = 1;
   
       while k <= maxk {
           while n <= maxn {
--             result += 1.0 / (k as i64 * (((n + 1) as i32).pow((2 * k) as u32)) as i64) as f64;
+              result += 1.0 / (k as f64 * (((n + 1) as f64).powf((2 * k) as f64))) as f64;
 +             result += 1. / k as f64 / (1. + n as f64).powf(2. * k as f64);
               n += 1;
           }
           n = 1;
           k += 1;
       }
       result
   }
```